# New rare-event regression method somewhere between logistic and survival

Tags: classification, bayesian, survival

I keep running into situations (in my job) where I need to predict relatively rare events that occur at most once per entity, across many entities, and over time (e.g. predicting mortality of cancer patients based on treatments given).

I’ve gone through this process a few times applying both survival/hazard models as as well as cost-aware classifiers (or the myriad of other ways to bend a classifier to deal with imbalance) and found a few commonalities that I thought seemed to suggest an opportunity for research.

Basically, I find that classifiers work well in those scenarios and generally have more desirable properties but there is always one critical modeling question that has to be answered in order to cast survival problems as classification ones — over what time period in the future are you trying to predict the event in question?

To phrase this as an example, say I’m trying to predict when my car will break down based on how many miles it has and how many of the sensor/warning lights are on.  As a survival regression problem, the objective is to estimate a probability curve for this failure time at some point in the future, but as a classification problem it must be reduced to a question like:

1. “will my car break down in the next 1-3 weeks?”.
2. “will it break down between 3 and 6 months from now?”
3. “will it break down tomorrow?”

My point is that choosing this interval for classification isn’t easy and in the past I’ve just done it based on the classifier performance for a ton of different interval possibilities and tried to find some setting that gives the best performance.

**My question then**:  Is anyone aware of a joint modeling strategy for both a binary classifier and the, let’s call it, “time-to-event” interval length?  It seems like it would be possible with an MCMC sampler and an appropriate probability model, and I wanted to see if that kind of regression has already been tried before.

Comment: You can "read off" logistic models for given time intervals from a survival model, fit using e.g. Cox proportional hazards.

Comment: On re-reading your question I'm a bit puzzled, because it's the application that mandates what you need to predict. Whether it's more useful to predict the probability that your car will break down tomorrow or the probability that your car will break down in the next three months depends on whether you're using your model to choose between driving & taking the bus tomorrow or to decide it's time to start looking for a new car. There then follows the interesting question of when "cutting" a survival model for a given time interval might give better predictions than fitting a logistic model ...

Comment: ... to failure over a that time interval. So why are you *choosing* the interval?

Comment: Ah thanks for giving it a read.  I'm choosing it because the objective is simply to define probability of the event ever happening, which I find is only possible with reasonable accuracy for an interval that isn't too large (at some point, it's just too far in the future to predict well).  This sounds like a survival regression problem then but the problem I have with that is that I have no way of verifying out of sample accuracy, or at least not one that seems widely accepted for proportional hazards models.  I like those out of sample measures because they're easier to communicate, ...

Comment: better for model selection, and I just plain trust them more than something like some in-sample information criteria score.  So I lean towards classification where that's all better established but I really have no restrictions on the application side other than just "trying to predict things as far in advance as possible".   That make sense?

Comment: (1) The objective's still vague - if you really want to predict the probability of something ever happening, how are we to judge the utility of predicting just that, inaccurately, vs predicting the probability it'll happen tomorrow, accurately? (2) "Ever" is either a long time or until something else happens instead. The former suggests making a pragmatic definition of "a long time" & using logistic regression (or perhaps a classifier), or borrowing information from earlier censored observations with a survival model (which you can then "cut").  The latter suggests a competing risks ...

Comment: ... model. (3) The out-of-sample performance of any fit metric (e.g. Nagelkerke's coefficient of determination or  Somer's Dxy rank correlation coefficent) can be estimated on a hold-out sample or by resampling validation for survival models just as for any other model.

Comment: (1) Makes sense, the utility I'm proposing is maximum likelihood (as a function of logistic regression parameters and a cut point on the time interval).  Though I see how one could possibly want a different utility function there, but maximizing likelihood makes sense given that you could make the same argument you made against logistic regression -- that one needs some utility in order to determine the value of a true negative or false positive (which is not necessarily true and maximum likelihood as a default is common)

Comment: (2) Yea I hear you there too, though I know the event will occur eventually and while I could come up with a pragmatic definition of what a long time is, I'd prefer it was set based on the accuracy of the models assuming some definition of "long time" leads to better performance (since there is no other context in the application that implies a meaningful cutoff).

Comment: (3) Cool!  I had never heard of those though in some quick googling they still look like in-sample estimates of out of sample error right?  How does resampling validation for survival models work?  That sounds much more promising as a direct, out of sample performance measure (but I don't know how it works).

Comment: (1) I just meant "what's the use?". If you need to be able to predict (or classify by, or rank) the probability that a car'll break down before the end of its two-year warranty period, then however good your prediction (or classification, or ranking) of the probability that it'll break down after six months, or ten years, according to whatever metric, it's an answer to the wrong question. (2) If you already *know* the event'll occur eventually you don't need a model. Sorry to be harping on about these points, but I worry that your question won't be answered unless they're addressed directly.

Comment: (3) Resampling methods comprise bootstrapping validation & cross-validation (leave-one-out or $k$-fold). The choice of fit metric is a separate issue (though not quite independent).

Comment: Perhaps the car example was a bad one -- I was using that as a bit of a simplification but I'll try to just cut to the core of what I'm getting at instead.  I think the fundamental predictability of an "event" for the entities I often work with differs by group.  I think that for some of them those events can be predicted well in advance and for others they cannot, and regardless of whether or not I have covariates useful for measuring that distinction I still have the problem that I don't know of a modeling framework that will handle this situation well.  I didn't want to complicate my ...

Comment: original explanation by introducing this hierarchical separation, but it seems like that might help make the utility of the approach more clear (in addition to putting the problem back in the classification domain where performance measures are easier to explain and use).  So the question I’m trying to answer is not just when is an event likely to occur but also how far in advance is it reasonable to assume those predictions are accurate.

Comment: In some simulations I’ve run producing events by entity with a probability taken as a linear model of random covariates, the likelihood of a logistic model fit to that data is always concave when taken as a function of the “time-to-event interval” (err still not sure what to call it).  To me this seems to imply that if I don’t have that interval length handed as a constraint in a problem, then I ought to make it variable and optimize models against it as well.

Comment: Oh and the resampling techniques make sense, I thought you might have meant something other than bootstrapped measures and cross validation.  Oy this comment chain is getting crazy haha so thank you for the feedback and I think I'll take this and results of my simulations/tests and try to turn them into a better question.